# What is wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is the SQL query I wrote in MS Access 07:

```
IF EXISTS (Select * FROM MyTable) print 'Yes' else print 'No'
```

This is the error it's giving me when i run the query:

> "Invalid SQL Statemenet; Expected DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT, UPDATE"

The query is correct, as far as I know, I think it's from Access, can anyone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what you actually want to do?
Do you want to check if there's data in the table, or do you want to check if the table even exists?

Comment: There are a lot of similar things can be done in either Access VBA or Jet SQL, DCount springs to mind, so if you would like to clarify the problem, I am sure a solution can be found.

Comment: This question is simply unanswerable until information is provided about what you're trying to accomplish and where.

Comment: It's disappointing that you simply accepted an answer without providing any of the information everyone was clamoring for.

Comment: This was a simplified example of what i'm trying to do, just to see why it does not work. But now, thanks to you all, i understood that Accept does not accept this kind of statements, so i thought te subject is closed. Anyway, thank you very much to all of you for your helpful hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points:

1. Access SQL uses `iif()`, not `IF`
2. <strike>Access SQL doesn't use EXISTS</strike>
   **Edit**:
   Actually it does work, even though I couldn't find it in the help files. This works fine:
   `Select (IIf(Exists (SELECT 1 FROM [Table1]),'Y','N')) as A from [Table1];`
   **/Edit**
3. DCount is the key:
   `iif(

   DCount("AnyFieldName","TableName")>0,

   "Yes",

   "No"`
4. I suggest bookmarking this site for future reference.  Really helpful.
   http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/
5. The Access help files are actually pretty helpful and straightforward. They describe parameters, output, give examples, etc. I recommend using them frequently.

Comment: To be clear regarding point 2, Jet/Access SQL does have an `EXISTS` operator.  It is perfectly valid to write a query using an expression like `IIf(Exists (SELECT 1 FROM [TableName]),'Y','N')`.

Comment: I made #2 on the basis that I've never heard of it before and I couldn't find it in the help files.  Thanks for the correction:)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `IF EXISTS` in Access. EXISTS() is allowed but only as an evaluative expression, not a procedural one. The EXISTS() expression returns True or False (in the form of -1 and 0).

Imagine that you *could* use a procedural expression... where are you trying to PRINT the result? There is no place for text results to be printed.

Please describe more clearly what problem you're trying to solve, and where you want the results to appear, and we can help you better.

Taking a wild guess, if you did want a query to return 'Yes' or 'No' then this can do it for you:

```
SELECT Iif(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable), "Yes", "No") AS MyTableHasRows
FROM Numbers
WHERE Num = 1;
```

There's a problem here, though: Access doesn't allow SELECT statements that don't refer to a table. (SQL Server allows this, and Oracle offers the fake DUAL table to select from.) One way around this is to select from a table that has only one row. My query above selects from a Numbers table that's in my test database, where only one row has `Num = 1`. Selecting from a table with many rows makes the engine do extra work for no reason.

If you want to do this checking in code, here's the best-performing way I can think of:

```
If CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT Top 1 * FROM MyTable").RecordCount > 0 Then
   Debug.Print "Yes"
Else
   Debug.Print "No"
End If
```

This is logically identical to EXISTS and will perform better than COUNT(*) which has to look at every row in the table.

Comment: You CAN use `EXISTS` in Access e.g. Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015(office.10).aspx): "The EXISTS predicate is used in subqueries to check for the existence of values in a result set... "

Comment: You can also do this: `SELECT DISTINCT IIF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable), 1, 0) FROM Customers;`

Comment: @onedaywhen Thank you for the correction! Please see my changes. Is that better? An undo would be appreciated.

Comment: @onedaywhen - thanks! I also fixed my weird duplication (obviously a paste error)

Answer (score 2):

`IF EXISTS` cannot be used in MS Access.

Take a look at this [link](http://www.eraserve.com/tutorials/MS_ACCESS_VBA_Check_If_Table_Exists.asp), it might be what you are after.

Comment: What do you mean by "tried, the same thing"? If you want help, you're going to have to do more than the web equivalent of mumbling.

Comment: But you can use `...IIF(EXISTS...` e.g. `SELECT DISTINCT IIF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable), 1, 0) FROM Customers;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a table has records in it, you can check CurrentDB.TableDefs("MyTable").Recordcount. That will never be 0 for a table with records in it.

Now, where you can use that is a different kettle of fish, but your question is so vague as to make it impossible to provide anything other than generalized approaches to solving the problem (which hasn't really been defined in the first place).

Comment: Alternatively: `CurrentProject.Connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaStatistics, Array(Empty, Empty, "MyTable")).Fields("CARDINALITY").Value` -- p.s. congratulations on attaining your ms-access badge ;)

Comment: I don't quite understand why it's giving me the bronze badge (100 upvotes) today when I earned the silver badge (400 upvotes) in the same tag some time ago. Seems to me something is screwed up somewhere along the line (only @Remou and I have the MS-ACCESS silver badge!).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a `BEGIN - END`.

UPDATE: Sorry to be the bearer of **bad news**.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS_Access/Q_22102849.html

Looks like MS Access has no control of flow execution in its SQL syntax.
It only executes a single command. (based on the link above)

Apparently there is no conditional statement in MS Access.

Comment: looks like you can do the if exists statement in access

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: Access has a light version from SQL. You won't be able to use TSQL.
You can try to use vba to achieve what you want.

Comment: Now that's what I thought, that this is rather a software problem than a sql query problem. But I need to use Access and i don't know how to solve it. Do you how other idea?

Comment: Access has modules and macros. You can use these to program your actions. You can run SQL in VBA via ADO I think, but there are also build in functions to test tables. Like dmax, dcount, dmin, ...

Answer (score 0):

As others said before me, Access doesn't know IF EXISTS.
You could do something like this in VBA:

```
Public Sub Foo()

    If Not IsNull(DLookup("SomeColumn", "MyTable")) Then
        MsgBox "yes"
    Else
        MsgBox "no"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea about MS Access, but what about the following:

```
IF SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE somecondition) THEN...
```

The error message "Invalid SQL Statemenet; Expected DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT, UPDATE"
suggests you are missing one of those. You need to SELECT EXISTS, rather than just calling EXISTS.

This works in PostgreSQL, but I'm not sure if Access is different.

Comment: Thanks, but no, it doesn't work here. It gives me the same error